# LINQ Select and concatenate results from hierarchical model

Tags: c#, .net, linq, silverlight

I have the below model which represents a two level menu hierarchy and what I need to do is select one ID from the `SubMenuItems` sub collection then concatenate the results from its and its parent records `TextToDisplay` properties.

The question I have is how to return a single parent item and a single sub item then access the `TextToDisplay` property?

The object that I want to query is an `ObserableCollection`

```
public ObservableCollection<MenuModel> MenuItems { get; set; }
```

**Model**

```
public class MenuModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string TextToDisplay { get; set; }
    public string ImageSource { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<MenuModel> SubMenuItems { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Single()` to get one item, and `Any()` to check if there is an element of a list which matches a query:

```
int theIdYouWant = 30; //for example
var parentItem = MenuItems.Single(i => i.SubMenuItems.Any(si => si.Id == theIdYouWant));
var text = parentItem.TextToDisplay + 
    parentItem.SubMenuItems.Single(i => i.Id == theIdYouWant).TextToDisplay;
```

Note this will throw an exception if no parent item contains a sub item with the ID of 30, or if more than one parent item is returned - so you may need to use `SingleOrDefault()` instead and check for null, or `Where` and then choose which item you want.

Comment: I would be careful using `Single()`, as it gives an exception of no object is found. I recommend using `SingleOrDefault()` instead.

Comment: @PatrikW Yes, I actually just added a sentence explaining the very thing.

Comment: What does the query in (i => query) represent?

Comment: Whatever query you need to get the parent item you want. (From your question: "how to return a single parent item".) If there is only one parent item in the hierarchy, just use `MenuItems.Single()` without the predicate. Again, this will throw an exception if `MenuItems` is empty or there is no match, so be careful.

Comment: Thanks lc but thats the problem I have. I need to select the parent based on the ID of the child then select the text from both.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand that the first time. I have updated my answer. If you have a 2-level hierarchy this will work, otherwise you will have to write a function that does a recursive Where.

Comment: Thank you lc. that fixed it. Very complex Linq query

Comment: Well, it's only nested once, so I'm not sure it falls in the "very complex" category yet, but it's more complicated than some. Glad this helped.